# How to send and receive push notifications for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I followed Microsofts article about sending and receiving push notifications on Windows Phone 8.0:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx

It works fine, but now we are creating a new Windows Phone 8.1 app and try to rewrite the same 8.0 code, but some classes are not available in WP 8.1.

Please help me how we can implement these for Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my class which I use for receiving push notifications and handling the `ChannelUri`. Just call the `UpdateChannelUri` method. The channelUri will be updated if need and the `ChannelUriUpdated` event will be fired and the same will be saved to application data settings.

If your app is running and you receive a notification, one of the four methods with notification content will be executed, determined by the notification type.

```
public sealed class PushService
{
    private const string ChannelUriKey = "ChannelUri";
    private const string ChannelUriDefault = null;

    private PushNotificationChannel _channel;

    private string _channelUri;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Services.PushService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public PushService()
    {
        this._channelUri = LocalSettingsLoad(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings, ChannelUriKey, ChannelUriDefault);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the push notification channel URI. If no channel URI was yet created
    /// then the value will be <c>null</c>.
    /// </summary>
    public string ChannelUri
    {
        get { return _channelUri; }
        private set
        {
            if (_channelUri != value)
            {
                this._channelUri = value;
                LocalSettingsStore(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings, ChannelUriKey, value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Requests a new push channel URI.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<string> UpdateChannelUri()
    {
        var retries = 3;
        var difference = 10; // In seconds

        var currentRetry = 0;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                _channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
                _channel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;
                if (!_channel.Uri.Equals(ChannelUri))
                {
                    ChannelUri = _channel.Uri;
                    // TODO send channel uri to your server to your server
                    this.RaiseChannelUriUpdated();
                    return _channel.Uri;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Could not create a channel
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(difference));

        } while (currentRetry++ < retries);

        return null;
    }

    private void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.NotificationType)
        {
            case PushNotificationType.Badge:
                this.OnBadgeNotificationReceived(args.BadgeNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Tile:
                this.OnTileNotificationReceived(args.TileNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Toast:
                this.OnToastNotificationReceived(args.ToastNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Raw:
                this.OnRawNotificationReceived(args.RawNotification.Content);
                break;
        }

        args.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void OnBadgeNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a badge notification is received when app is running
    }

    private void OnTileNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a tile notification is received when app is running
    }

    private void OnToastNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a toast notification is received when app is running

        // Show a toast notification programatically

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(notificationContent);
        var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);

        //toastNotification.SuppressPopup = true;
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
    }

    private void OnRawNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a raw notification is received when app is running
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ChannelUriUpdated;
    private void RaiseChannelUriUpdated()
    {
        if (ChannelUriUpdated != null)
        {
            ChannelUriUpdated(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public static T LocalSettingsLoad<T>(ApplicationDataContainer settings, string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        T value;

        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            value = (T)settings.Values[key];
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise use the default value.
            value = defaultValue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static bool LocalSettingsStore(ApplicationDataContainer settings, string key, object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;

        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            // If the key exists
            if (settings.Values[key] != value)
            {
                // If the value has changed, store the new value
                settings.Values[key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise create the key
            settings.Values.Add(key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Kristian   Sir how we get LocalSettings class

Comment: sir I tried add for LocalSetting so it look like    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["key"] = value; please help

Comment: @Krishtian we are use same class but not getting a channel URI

Comment: Have you specified that your application is toast capable in the application manifest?

Comment: Yes I Set toast capabale is  Yes

Comment: Sir how we get the channel URL.

Comment: @ Kristian Sir how we can get the channel URL.

Comment: @ Kristian I call Method UpdateChannelUri() then i got URL Like This https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAABrmu5ujnexR61g%2bcMw6ypILgPVcQYr%2b7Pr3BbjNP7MLEYekh%2bmgYsW%2bEY%2blFDGoHd1mhg0OMGBRNcm3jYMELWrFkxQ1C23DhMyMSvl2pa1CL1xYgUqxJeqNAZK0C61Ay8%3d

Comment: @ Kristian But not getting the Toast in our app.

Comment: @KristianVukusic Thanks for answer. I tried your code. I want to ask one thing is there any way to call this function in background. I have written my server side uri update code inside this class. So that's why I want to run this method in background.