# WNS implementation with AWS SNS on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, windows-phone-8.1, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement WNS and AWS-SNS on Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Everything is fine at AWS-SNS end, but I am not able to receive WNS notification on Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Have you tried sending yourself a toast notification with the tools that come with emulators? Just to ensure that you can receive notifications.

Comment: @KristianVukusic thanks for replying, yes i can receive notifications . 
Even i can send notifications from windows to other phones(android,iOS) .
But when i try to send to windows phone 8.1 itself, it doesn't do anything .

Comment: How do you retrieve the channel url in your app?

Comment: channel url is being retrieved as mentioned in MSDN documentations, and it's returning channel uri ,it's working fine and i am using same channel uri in event listener  ! as i said the only issue is reception of notification on windows phone 8.1 .

Comment: @KristianVukusic if you have already implemented WNS background task (event listener ) for pushnotification , can you please share the code ?

Comment: Then have you specified that you app is Toast capable in the Application manifest?

Comment: Yes @KristianVukusic that i have done too . can you please share some code if you have done it already ?

Comment: I have not done it in a Background Task, but instead directly in my app. See my answer on another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096929/how-to-send-and-receive-push-notifications-for-windows-phone-8-1/32098201#32098201)

Comment: thanks @KristianVukusic  my problem solved :)

Comment: @KristianVukusic I have used your Service you told me,it's working fine. Another Issue m facing is how to updated UI from this service . thanks in advance :)